# firefox extension and ie8 plugin compatibility

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8

im a bit new at extension development, but im about to embark upon a project to build a ffox extension.

Does anyone know if its possbile, with minimal adaption, to make a firefox extension compatible with ie8 as a plugin and if so, are there any caveats i should be aware of?

I guess its just javascript code wrapped around the ffox or ie8 wrapper, but would really appreciate to learn from someone who has experience.

Cheers

Ke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others may know better than I but I don't think there's any "minimal adaptation" (<- I'm assuming you meant to say "adaptation") way to do this.  IE plugins are COM and FF plugins are coded with JavaScript and XUL.

Comment: yep this is what i was looking for, even tho its simple it helps me a lot cheers :)